# Blackberry sending mail problem

Tags: email, blackberry, spam

Hey all got a pretty simple question here:

[A LITTLE BACKGROUND]

We use a service called Google Postini and part of Postini is a service called IP-Lock.  What IP-Lock does is if an individual attempts to send mail posing as our exchange server but in fact the IP address does not match our exchange server than our own mail server will reject the email as spam.
On occasion we've had to add IP addresses to the whitelist to allow for emails to come through.  This is great if we can get the IP address(s) from the service or company that is sending on behalf of.

[THE PROBLEM]

We have users who are using mainly iPhone and Android based phones.  The iPhone and Android phones use ActiveSync and they work flawlessly.
However, the users that are using Blackberry phones have an issue:
When they send from the phone to reply to emails only to our domain... these emails are rejected because the IP address is coming from blackberry and not the exchange server.  When sending to other email accounts not on our domain the emails will go through fine.  Also if the reply is sent from a gmail account or yahoo this will work fine.
It is only when the email is sent from our domain, to our domain and only on blackberry devices.
So iPhones, and Android phones send using our own server and they use completely active sync.  Blackberry seems to want to send out using its own method.
We had a blackberry enterprise server and did away with this because it costs money.  Using iPhones and Androids do not cost any extra in fees.
We will not be using any blackberry enterprise services so this is not an option.

[WHAT I NEED]

A: A direct contact at Blackberry that will provide me a list of all IP addresses for blackberry mail servers that are sending out mail so we can add those IP’s to our IP-Lock whitelist.

B: A list of ALL the IP addresses that blackberry uses to send out mail so we can add it to our whitelist.

C: A way to change the blackberry devices settings so that they send mail the same way the iPhone and Droid does.
Thanks in advance for any solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a list of Blackberry IP addresses at:

http://www.blackberry.com/btsc/search.do?cmd=displayKC&docType=kc&externalId=KB11036

I've used this in the past to whitelist firewall connections to RIM's SRP servers, but it seems to be intended to cover all of their servers.

Note that going down this route will mean that anyone using a Blackberry will be able to spoof your domain and get around the IP lock settings, though this is probably OK if you're just guarding against spam.

Answer (score 0):

This only addresses part C of your question:

The one thing I can tell you for sure, is that all blackberry traffic gets routed to the 'mothership' and that is not something that can be changed, as it depends on RIM's network.

How many blackberries are we talking about?  What about using the smaller version of BES, the Blackberry Professional Software?

From having managed Blackberries in the past, the software route could be the *least* painful.  It will not anywhere as simple as the Androids, or iPhones.

Answer (score 0):

If BES is not an option for you, "LogicMail for blackberry" (http://www.logicmail.org) provides SMTP/IMAP/POP support, so you can choose the outgoing mail server from the device.

Anyway, I'd prefer a BES server to have under control those Blackberries. Our provider (Vodafone Spain) does not charge us for the BES license (we have 100+ devices, don't know about your situation, but maybe you can re-negotiate it)

References:
15 Free Tools to Turn Your BlackBerry into a Communications Powerhouse
http://mashable.com/2009/01/06/free-blackberry-communications-apps/